# How does jQuery handle attribute getters/setters with multiple matches?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I know that the jQuery selector returns an object of matching DOM elements, e.g.

```
typeof $('p'); // returns "object"
```

But when I try to access all elements in the object, it seems the only effect the first, e.g.

```
$('p').html('test'); // only sets the first <p></p> to test
```

I know I can do

```
$('p').each(function() { $(this).html('test') });
```

But is this the preferred method? Is there some other way to set mass attributes?

---

EDIT: Sorry guys, I was trying to access the wrong tag :( and it was unrelated to any jQuery issue. But everything said below is useful and might be helpful to someone so I won't close the question.

Comment: [No, it does not](http://jsfiddle.net/K5EeY/)

Comment: Your wrong im afraid ... check this http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/C8BrU/

Comment: "But when I try to access all elements in the object, it seems the only effect the first."  It does? http://jsfiddle.net/LShK8/

Comment: @Sam Grondahl - Can you edit your question so that it clarifies the context of the answers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to apply to all the `p`, then there is no need to loop. You can just apply by:

```
$("p").html('test');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swamimayank/jXHRr/)

Comment: To elaborate, for the "getter" most methods return the first result, while the "setter" typically affects all.  The docs are a little sparse on this but most will hint at it.  [html does](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

Answer (score 2):

This is not correct, `jQuery.html()` will set **all** matching elements. See the documentation:

> Set the HTML contents of each element in the set of matched elements.

http://api.jquery.com/html/

See working example: http://jsfiddle.net/zqYgQ/

---

However, you are right that some methods only apply to the first matching element. In which case, your method would be the best practice:

```
$('p').each(function() { 
   $(this).someMethod();
});
```

---

In reverse, if you wish to **only** apply to the first element for a method which applys to all matched, you can filter/select only the first by using 1 of the following methods:

```
$("p:first").method();

$("p")[0].method();
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not set only the first `p` , it would change all of them, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bfJcL/) for example

Answer (score 0):

That is not the case :
http://jsfiddle.net/TjxyL/

Answer (score 0):

You're wrong though, it does set all the elements, see: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J7DRC/)

```
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>

<script>
    ​$('p').html('test');​
</script>
```